# Why does whitespace not matter in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My question is fairly simple but after looking around a bit I still have no idea why this even compiles- nevermind produce the correct result (Python 3.10).

```
# Testing conjunction/disjunction boolean values of a and b
a = 1
b = 2

# AND
a == 1and b == 2
True
a == 1and b == 1
False
a == 2and b == 1
False
a == 2and b == 2
False

# OR
a == 1or b == 2
True
a == 1or b == 1
True
a == 2or b == 1
False
a ==2or b == 2
True
```

Not only does python not mind the lack of whitespace, but it also produces the correct results for both "and" and "or"

Maybe this is due to Python parsing code in some particular way, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [language spec](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#whitespace-between-tokens):

> Whitespace is needed between two tokens only if their concatenation
> could otherwise be interpreted as a different token (e.g., ab is one
> token, but a b is two tokens).